# Send json data for json get request in odoo 12

Tags: json, api, controller, postman, odoo

I want send json data from odoo controller.For that i have created below controller

```
from odoo.http import Response
import json


@http.route('/api/json_get_request',auth='public',type='json',methods=["GET"],csrf=False)
    def printjson(self,**kw):

        headers={'content-type':'application/json'}    
        return Response(json.dumps({"test":"json string"}),headers=headers)
```

but accessing http://localhost:8089/api/json_get_request in postman gives me Invalid json data then I have check postman console in that response header -> Content-Type: "text/html" is shown.
Not understand after sending data in the json type why json data not recieved.

After accessing http://localhost:8089/api/json_get_request as http request on postman gives me correct json data.
 Please give me suggestion
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing method that handle 'json' request should return a dictionary directly:

```
@http.route('/api/json_get_request', auth='public', type='json',  csrf=False)
def printjson(self, **kw):
    return {'attribute': 'test'}
```

this will return a result like this:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": null,
  "result": {
    "attribute": "test"
  }
}
```

You are having this error because you didn't send any `json` data with the request.
You could test your code using the `requests` module:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> url = 'http://localhost:8069/api/json_get_request'
>>> data = {'params': {'test': 100}}
>>> headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
>>> requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
<Response [404]>
```

It gives me this error because there is no database selected, and I have more than one database.
If you have only one database you see the correct result.
but when you test it from Postman extension I used [RESTED](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rested/)

[image]

Because I'm all ready logged to Odoo the method was executed successfully , Just look for a better postman extension or search how to send `json` data with your current postman. You need to send some json data in the request.

Comment: Thanks @Charif DZ for your time and answer.  Yes I haven't send json data that is the reason error was occur. After sending json data and return dictionary as a converting into json [json.dumps({"test":"json string"})]  gives me result. can you please share link or documents regarding requests used in python for odoo

Comment: I really don't have any documents, I akways go to Odoo code and read it and try to understand what is going on. They done plenty of things there some reading and testing and googling you will learn anything.